# ValueError when using plt.quiver: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, matplotlib, valueerror

I simply try to plot a 2d quiver plot in matplotlib, showing a transect of divergent zonal wind (=u) and vertical velocity (=v), with longitudes (-180 to 180) on the x-axis and geopotential height on the y axis (1000hP to 40hPa). I normalized the length of the arrows for visualisation purposes and now want the width of the arrow/shaft to represent the wind speed (sqrt(u²+v²)).
However, when I use the following code I get the error below:

```
width = np.sqrt(u**2+v**2)
ax.quiver(data['x'].values, data['plev'].values / 100, 
          u, v,
          width=width.values.flatten())
```

Error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (832,8) (832,)
```

However, when I do

```
print(plt_data_plev['x'].values.shape)
print(plt_data_plev['plev'].values.shape)
print(u.shape)
print(v.shape)
print(width.values.flatten().shape)
```

gives:

```
(64,)
(13,)
(13, 64)
(13, 64)
(832,)
```

I really don't understand where the problem lies here.
Grateful for help.

I also already tried flattening the x,y and u and v into 1d array (len=832) but it gives the same error. When I remove the width parameter, it works fine.

Comment: Note that the documentation only mentions "float" for the `width` argument, not array. So perhaps (and unliked various other styling parameters in Matplotlib) `width` can't take an array.

Comment: Additionally to the comment above: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8630